# routing legacy asp.net links in an asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following url I need to support in my asp.net mvc project for a while.

```
http://www.example.com/d.aspx?did=1234
```

I need to map this to this url.

```
http://www.example.com/Dispute/Detail/1234
```

I have already looked at the following information.

http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/04/ASPNET-MVC---Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx

[ASP.Net MVC routing legacy URLs passing querystring Ids to controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817325/asp-net-mvc-routing-legacy-urls-passing-querystring-ids-to-controller-actions)

In trying to follow this I can get the first url to work but then all other url's are broken. **Can anyone see my where I have gone wrong?**

Here are my routes.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // all my other routes

        // Legacy routes
        routes.Add(
          "Legacy", 
          new LegacyRoute(
            "d.aspx", 
            "LegacyDirectDispute", 
            new LegacyRouteHandler())
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "LegacyDirectDispute", 
          "Dispute/Details/{id}",
          new { controller = "Dispute", action = "Details", id = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Default",                                              // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                       // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Here is code in my global.asax.cs I am using.

```
 public class LegacyRoute : Route
 {
  public string RedirectActionName { get; set; }
  public LegacyRoute(string url, string redirectActionName, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
   : base(url, routeHandler)
  {
   RedirectActionName = redirectActionName;
  }
 }

 // The legacy route handler, used for getting the HttpHandler for the request
 public class LegacyRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
 {
  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) 
  {
   return new LegacyHandler(requestContext);
  }
 }

 // The legacy HttpHandler that handles the request
 public class LegacyHandler : MvcHandler
 {
  private RequestContext requestContext;
  public LegacyHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
   : base(requestContext)
  {
   this.requestContext = requestContext;
  }

  protected override void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
   string redirectActionName = ((LegacyRoute)RequestContext.RouteData.Route).RedirectActionName;

   var queryString = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
   foreach (var key in queryString.AllKeys)
   {
    if (key.Equals("did"))
    {
     requestContext.RouteData.Values.Add("id", queryString["did"]);
    }
    else
    {
     requestContext.RouteData.Values.Add(key, queryString[key]);
    }
   }

   VirtualPathData path = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, redirectActionName,
                 requestContext.RouteData.Values);

   if (path != null)
   {
    httpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Location", path.VirtualPath);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817325/asp-net-mvc-routing-legacy-urls-passing-querystring-ids-to-controller-actions/818370#818370

Comment: @marwan-auida Please read the question content. I have already seen and read that SO question and I even have a link to it in my question.

Comment: What I mean by my url's being broken is before I add the LegacyRouteHandler code I had links like http://www.example.com/News and now they come up http://www.example.com/d.aspx?action=Index&controller=News.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just create a file called d.aspx in your site root with contents similar to the following:

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}/Dispute/Detail/{1}", Request.Url.Host, Request.QueryString.Get("did")));
}
</script>
```

Comment: @grenade I like this it is the simplest answer I have seen to this problem.

Comment: Since this is also for SEO purposes, I recommend the RedirectPermanent method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up doing to resolve my problem until I saw the simple answer @grenade posted. I found this technique here http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/108/Handling-Legacy-URLs-with-ASP.NET-MVC.

```
public class LegacyUrlRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        const string status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var legacyUrl = request.Url.ToString();
        var newUrl = "";
        var id = request.QueryString.Count != 0 ? request.QueryString[0] : "";

        if (legacyUrl.Contains("d.aspx"))
        {
            newUrl = "Dispute/Details/" + id;
            response.Status = status;
            response.RedirectLocation = newUrl;
            response.End();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext,
                RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // all my other routes
    routes.Add(new LegacyUrlRoute());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a Map page route:

```
Routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Legacy", // Route name
            "d.aspx", // URL
            "~/pathfromBaseUrl/d.aspx" // File
            );
```

Then using this in your aspx/view

```
Html.RouteLink("MyLinkName", "Legacy")
```