# ViewResult fails to return values once a new parameter (not id) is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, controller, query-string, actionresult

I have a bit of a weird issue with a record display.  If a user enters a bar-code numeric (int) value into a URL, I'm supposed to show the details of the record linked to that bar-code.  At one time, GUIDs (CodeId GUID PK) were used for the bar-codes, but now we are adding a new Int field (SerialId IDENTITY Int) to keep track of the actual bar-code value; we're not allowed to change the CodeId field on the table (which called Code), so this leads to my odd issue.  I've looked around, and this [QueryString id parameter not being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146004/querystring-id-parameter-not-being-used) is the closest that I can find to addressing what's happening with me.

My Routing is perfectly normal

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Model is normal

```
public DbSet<Code> Codes { get; set; }

public partial class Code
{
    public System.Guid CodeId { get; set; }
    public int SerialId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BarCodeDescr { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
}
```

My controller worked just fine when things were a GUID, and the Id mapped to CodeId (the table's PK) etc.

```
    public ViewResult BarCode(Guid id)
    {
        Code code = db.Codes.Find(id);
        return View(code);
    }
```

Now I'm trying to do something more like this:

```
    public ViewResult BarCode(int serialid)
    {
        Code code = db.Codes.Find(serialid);
        return View(code);
    }
```

or this...

```
    public ActionResult QRCode(int serialid)
    {
        ViewData["SerialId"] = serialid;
        return View(db.Codes.Where(x => x.SerialId == serialid).ToList());
    }
```

...only all my attempts lead to the same error:

```
 The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'serialid' 
 of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult 
 BarCode(Int32)' in 'MyProject.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter 
 must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
 Parameter name: parameters
```

What am I doing wrong?  It's not ideal to have my view return a record based on searching for a specific SerialId instead of the CodeId, but it should be do-able, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try using an optional parameter?

```
public ViewResult BarCode(int serialid = 0)
    {
        Code code = db.Codes.Find(serialid);
        return View(code);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, no, that's a new idea to me.  In trying it, I've got a different error: {"The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.\r\nParameter name: keyValues"}  {"The argument types 'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.Int32' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 70."}  ...which seems to be saying that it is still trying to return the view assuming that the value will go against CodeId/the GUID.

Comment: Double check your database column type and maybe trying to refresh if you are using Entity Framework with a .edmx file

Comment: Ok, I double-checked and it is definitely SerialId (INT) with identity insert ON.  And the .edmx is refreshed.  No changes; I then tried public ViewResult BarCode(int? serialid = 0) with the ? after the int, and got a new error about properly identified PK values (which SerialId is not the PK, CodeId is.)  {"The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.\r\nParameter name: keyValues"}  The inner exception is the same: where Edm.Guid and Edm.Int32 are not compatible.  Is my ViewResult trying to make the PK go in the INT?

Comment: Might want to look at a re-build or delete the files in the bin and obj folders or delete the .edmx file and re-add it.  Creating a new project/solution w/ your code in isolation to see if there is another dependency that is causing the issue.

Comment: Christopher, thank you for all your help.  I'm not certain that this is solvable the way that I'm going about it; I'll ask for permission to change the Id from a GUID to an INT, and directly address the issue.