# Mapping querystrings in routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

A site uses this link format for everything:

- example.com/?article=123
- example.com/?category=456
- example.com/?article=789&picture=012

An ASP classic default.asp catches all of this and does stuff with it.

I would really like to create a couple of routes for these old type of Url's with querystrings on the root, so I can catch them in a separate controller and do some tricks on them (permanent redirects).

When I try to create a route that contains a questionmark, I am told that is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a good case for [Global Action Filters](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx) if there's no way to handle these using routes (Although I imagine there is).

You could process the incoming url in the `OnActionExecuting` method and redirect as appropriate.

**UPDATE**

There's a good [SO answer here on how to redirect as you require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817325/asp-net-mvc-routing-legacy-urls-passing-querystring-ids-to-controller-actions). It may not be exactly as you've asked however a similar principle should acheive what you're after quite easily.